# How do I take the value of a variable from the node template and insert it into the field value?

Tags: 9

In the template of the material type node there is a variable that adds and multiplies integers according to the formula, which I take from the filled fields of the node. Everything is working properly.

An example in which the variable "result_value" in the node template is assigned a value calculated by the formula:

```
{% set result_value = (5 + portfolio_result_value) * portfolio_event_status_value * portfolio_participant_value / portfolio_worker_value / program_form_value %}
```

At the output I get a number, for example 180. Next, at the moderation stage, I enter it manually in the "result" field of the "decimal number" type.

The question is, how do I pass the value of the variable "result_value" to the result field automatically after creating a node or when launching crowns?

Comment: This is a hard no-go and will never work with Twig. If you want to "pass the value" accross page loads, use PHP. If you want to "pass the value" between input fields on the same page after keyboard/mouse events, use JavaScript.

Comment: How would you do in PHP, describe the procedure? I am now considering the option to do this via https://www.drupal.org/project/eca But I can't find a way yet

Comment: Needs to be the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer in my case is either to write your own module with your own logic, which will substitute the necessary values into the fields through hooks:

- hook_entity_presave() - will add when creating the material
- hook_entity_upadte() - will add it after updating the material

Or use a ready-made mathematical expressions module, I used this one: https://www.drupal.org/project/field_expression

The module adds a special type of field in which, using tokens, you can substitute and calculate the values of the material fields according to the desired formula. The value is recalculated every time the material is updated and stored in the database, it can be output in a template or used to implement some other logic.

In my case, I use the taxonomy field in the material, the user selects a term from a certain dictionary. Each term has a numeric field where a certain score is stored, this field is easy to output via tokens, and the score can always be easily changed if necessary.

In the final value of the field looks like this:

```
(5+[node:field_portfolio_result:entity:field_competitive_events_score])*[node:field_portfolio_event_status:entity:field_competitive_events_score]*[node:field_portfolio_participant_sum:value]/[node:field_portfolio_worker]/[node:field_portfolio_participat_form:entity:field_competitive_events_score]
```

Also in one place I needed to substitute the number of elements that I refer to through the reference field. In tokens, it was not possible to output this as a number, so I used this module, which simply adds a field formatter that counts the number of elements and outputs a number: https://www.drupal.org/project/field_count_formatter. I installed it, turned on the "Token" viewing mode for my material, and there, in the field display settings, I chose the way to display the field I needed. As a result, everything works as I need it.

There is a similar module for Views, so that it is possible to perform mathematical calculations in the view: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_simple_math_field

There is also a module that allows you to add the values of other Views fields: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_cumulative_field